# How to run selenium tests on Safari using Selenoid?

Tags: selenium, safari, selenoid, automation-testing

I'd like to ask, maybe somebody had experience with running automation tests on Safari (there are some strict limitations for Windows and Linux machines). One approach that I detected - it's Selenoid (but when run it, I get: "

```
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.


Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '......'
System info: host: 'runner-ovqpgybp-project-31983248-concurrent-0', ip: '.....', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-1017-gcp', java.version: '17.0.1'
selenide.remote: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Let me know if there exist some solution or workaround, please.

Answer (score 0):

We provide Webkit-based Docker images for that:

```
$ cat browsers.json
{
    "safari": {
        "default": "15.0",
        "versions": {
            "15.0": {
                "image": "browsers/safari:15.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a real Safari, but browser engine is the same and it works in Docker.